# Move a number's position to get the right equation

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle

$62-5+3*2=25$

Move a number's position in order to get the right equation.

Comment: We can just move a digit or a number but not add any other mathematical function? right?

Comment: @Netham yes, only the number. eg., if you're moving the "-5" somewhere, you should move it as a whole including the operator that precedes it, like that "-5."

Comment: ^ "move only the number"..."move operators too"

Comment: @jdoe179  Can you please update the question and fix the missing part pointed by @ feelinferrety

Comment: If this is move one number with one operator I don't think it can be solved.  Please clarify.

Comment: How do you make the equation equal and not flipping their signs? Did it ever happen before?

Answer (score 5):

Can't tell if moving one digit is all we're are allowed, but this one is SOOO close:

> $6^2-5-3\times2=36-11=25$.

Comment: how did the 3x2 become negative?

Comment: @JasonV 6^2-5-3×2 =36-5-6 = 31-6 = 25.  It seems correct or did I missed something?

Comment: @Alex that is a correct statement, but the original equation has 62 - 5 *+* 3x2.... this answer uses 62 -5 *-*3x2.

Comment: Given that addition having higher precedence than subtraction (and multiplication than division) is somewhat common misconception due to the order of the letters in PEMDAS, I wouldn't be too surprised if this is the intended answer, if the OP had intended 62-5+3*2 to be parsed as 62-(5+3*2).

Comment: @hvd the only way that happens is with the parentheses.

Comment: @JasonV Did you miss the word "misconception" in my comment? I am aware of that. :)

Answer (score 2):

> 62 is equivalent to 43+19. so we have 43+19-5+3x2=25. By moving the +19 to the RHS we are left with

The answer

> 43-5+3x2=25+19 ==> 43-5+6 = 44 ==>*44=44*

Reasoning

> I began this approach by looking into re-writing the constants as quotients (as in 275/55=5, then move the numerator 275 above the 25 to get 11, but this equation eventually works out to 13=11...) I am aware that my final method is not as eloquent as my original attempt, but I think it warrants being a correct answer. (and possibly spark some new ideas outside of the box) Afterall, I don't think anyone would argue with (62 is equivalent to 43+19).

Comment: moving +19 to RHS would make it -19.

Comment: @Abhishek that is the whole purpose of the puzzle, to not use the rules of math, but to simply *move* one operand and its leading operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think, following is right position.

> 25 - 6 + 3 x 2 = 25

Comment: That looks to me like more than one number has to be moved. What am I missing?

Comment: Yep, looks like a number swap instead of moving one number only.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I had the same doubt. It seems to assume that moving the number would keep the operations in the same indexes. i.e. 6253225 becomes 2563225 by moving the 6, then replacing the operations in their original indexes gives this answer.

Comment: Not even a number swap. It's a cyclic permutation of the first three digits.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

> 62 - 5 + m * 2 = 25 (assuming I can move the position of 3 so its on its side and then count it as an m)
>  simplified is then:
>  57 + 2m = 25
>  2m = -32
>  m = -16
>  It's an equation. if its the right one is up to preference

Answer (score -1):

Using the updated rule that you move an attached operator with the digit you can just move the

> x2

to the other side to get

> 62-5+3=25x2   ... (both sides now equal 50)

Comment: That math doesn't work.  Even if you fix the numbers (you flipped a 3 and a 5), it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah yes. 50 doesn't quite equal 60...